# Detecting winsock on i686-w64-mingw32msvc/Linux

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, autotools, winsock2

I have a program with configure script, that I want to cross compile on Linux for Windows.
In Ubuntu 11.10 I had these two lines in configure.in:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(winsock2.h)
AC_CHECK_LIB([ws2_32], [_head_libws2_32_a])
```

This was able to properly detect that the thing is being cross compiled for windows and added winsock to list of libraries to link with.

Now that on Ubuntu 12.04 i586-mingw32msvc has been discarded in favor of i686-w64-mingw32msvc,  this does not work anymore. Neither header not library are detected (although at least header is there). Can anyone point me to a right way to check for winsock on i686-w64-mingw32msvc/ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Reminded by Akshay about this issue I have investigated it some more. Replaced function in AC_CHECK_LIB with something definitely present, like WSAStartup/WSACleanup and it seems to me, that i686-w64-mingw32 toolchain is somehow broken on Ubuntu 12.04 as compilation of conftest fails complaining of undefined reference to _WSAStartup, unless it's defined exactly the same way as in winsock2.h. On the other hand i686-w64-mingw32 toolchain is fine with it. For this reason configure script does not detect winsock. So-so workaround: AC_CHECK_LIB(ws2_32, main).